# Wiping an image from Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to write an onclick function to the Image class so when you click on the image it will perform an action.

```
Image.prototype.onClick = function(x, y, w, h, id) {        
    window.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){
        if(mouseX >= parseInt(x) && mouseX <= parseInt(x) + parseInt(w) &&
            mouseY >= parseInt(y) && mouseY <= parseInt(y) + parseInt(h)) {

            console.log(id + ", " + x + ", " + y + ", " + w + ", " + h + ", " + mouseX + ", " + mouseY);
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Then I have the main method which is drawn:

```
function main() {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 640, 480);

    for(var obj in value) { 
        sprite.onClick(value[obj].X, value[obj].Y, 32, 32, value[obj].Id);
    }
}
```

So the problem I am currently having is that is clicks successfully, however it loops over the same image depending how many times it's been drawn.

[image]

So basically the image is being drawn whenever function is looped, I need a way to destroy the image from the canvas rather than drawing over it with a blank white rectangle.

Comment: When/where is the main method being called?

Comment: Within the setInterval function

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration of your timer it clears the canvas and calls images (I'm guessing to ask them if you clicked inside them) which **add**EventListener to mouseDown, so by the time you do press the mouse down the image will have many triggers attached to it which will all fire.

I think you are meaning to capture mouseDown on one trigger then do the check on all images in a loop - not attaching triggers to every object every frame.

There is no way to pick an object on the canvas to erase. Much like in MS Paint, once the pixels are drawn they're just pixels which have no connection to what they belong to.
Unless you know some specific rules about render order, layers and alpha its much simpler to redraw all objects every frame.